# How to find bin edges of given bin number returned by scipy.stats.binned_statistic_dd()?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, binning

I have a Nx3 array *mm*. The function call

```
c,edg,idx = scipy.stats.binned_statistic_dd(mm,[], statistic='count',bins=(30,20,10),rg=((3,5),(2,8),(4,6)))
```

returns **idx**, which is a 1d array of ints that represents the bin in which each element of **mm** falls, and **edg** is a list of 3 arrays holding the bin edges

What I need is to find the bin edges of a given bin given it's binnumber in idx. For example, given **idx**=[24,153,...,72] I want to find the edges of say bin 153, i.e. where that bin falls in **edg**. Of course I can find the elements in bin 153 by mm[153], but not the edges.

I posted this Nx3 case just for clarity. In reality, I am looking for a solution to the NxD case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to first be familiar with [np.unravel_index](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html). It converts a "flat index" (i.e. binnumber!) to a tuple of coordinates. You can think of the flat index as the index into `arr.ravel()`, and the tuple of coordinates as the index into `arr`.   For example, if in the diagram below we think of the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5 as bin numbers:

```
   | 0 | 1 | 2 |
---+---+---+---|
 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
   +---+---+---|
```

then `np.unravel_index(4, (2,3))`

```
In [65]: np.unravel_index(4, (2,3))
Out[65]: (1, 1)
```

equals `(1,1)` because the 4th bin number in an array of shape `(2,3)` has coordinate `(1,1)`.

Okay then. Next, we need to know that internally `scipy.stats.binned_statistic_dd` adds two edges to the given bin edges to handle outliers:

```
bin_edges = [np.r_[-np.inf, edge, np.inf] for edge in bin_edges]
```

So the edge coordinates corresponding to the bin numbers is given by

```
edge_index = np.unravel_index(binnumber, [len(edge)-1 for edge in bin_edges])
```

(We use `len(edge)-1` because the shape of the array axis is one less than the
number of edges.)

---

For example:

```
import itertools as IT
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

sample = np.array(list(IT.product(np.arange(5)-0.5, 
                                  np.arange(5)*10-5, 
                                  np.arange(5)*100-50)))
bins = [np.arange(4),
        np.arange(4)*10,
        np.arange(4)*100]

statistic, bin_edges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic_dd(
    sample=sample, values=sample, statistic='count', 
    bins=bins, 
    range=[(0,100)]*3)

bin_edges = [np.r_[-np.inf, edge, np.inf] for edge in bin_edges]
edge_index = np.unravel_index(binnumber, [len(edge)-1 for edge in bin_edges])


for samp, idx in zip(sample, zip(*edge_index)):
    vert = [edge[i] for i, edge in zip(idx, bin_edges)]
    print('{} goes in bin with left-most corner: {}'.format(samp, vert))
```

yields

```
[ -0.5  -5.  -50. ] goes in bin with left-most corner: [-inf, -inf, -inf]
[ -0.5  -5.   50. ] goes in bin with left-most corner: [-inf, -inf, 0.0]
[  -0.5   -5.   150. ] goes in bin with left-most corner: [-inf, -inf, 100.0]
[  -0.5   -5.   250. ] goes in bin with left-most corner: [-inf, -inf, 200.0]
...
```

Comment: Great solution unutbu. I had found unravel_index() and the extra bins of binned_statistic_dd(), but could not work out the full solution. I implemented a much less elegant solution by simply modifying binned_statistic_dd() source code to return Ncount, which holds the 1d bin numbers in each dimension for every input element. But yours is way more straightforward.